# The Privilege Page should show Rep Requirements for Post-Beta

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, launch

[There's a really informative page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges) that anyone can visit describing the various levels of reputation along with the benefits conferred by reaching each milestone. Currently, because we are in beta, the reputation required is reduced and those numbers are correctly shown.

However, we are now fast approaching graduation, and those reputation levels are going to change (hope this isn't too much of a surprise to anyone). I think it would be beneficial to have the post-graduation reputation levels listed as well.

So for example, instead of just having the "500" listed for [editing questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), we should have something along the lines of:

```
Reputation Required

500

(2000 post-beta)
```

Actual implementation of course would vary... But by adding this to all beta sites (or at least all beta sites that are approaching graduation) it will prevent confusion, and ease the transition.

<sub>Oh, and I will no longer have to suffer with a [side](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges)-by-[side](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) comparison with StackOverflow</sub>

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76557 (which has no on-point answer to date).

Comment: Incidentally, don't look at SO: according to the table linked to in DoubleAA's answer, SO is exceptional.

Comment: @msh210 Not quite an exact duplicate.

Comment: @msh210 And hence all the more reason to have the feature!

Comment: @msh210 Actually I'm quite confused. Aren't we in public beta? And if so, shouldn't editing require 1000?

Comment: We are in public beta, and editing seems to require 500. So I guess that table is wrong (or incomplete).

Comment: This is שייך for what, one more week??

Comment: @HahuGavra Better late than never. And the many sites that will come after us as well....

Comment: @yydl so it's more of a ואהבת לרעיך כמוך thing.

Comment: @yydl, isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: @msh210 He's asking for whether a person will retain it. I'm asking for a simple number. Yes - it is the same idea, but the real question: can cross-site duplicates exist?

Comment: Well, not a duplicate in the sense that one should be closed. I just meant it's a duplicate in the sense that it's asking the same question. And I suppose your distinction, fine though it is, is real.

Answer (score 5):

You can see a chart like that here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329/what-will-happen-when-we-launch-aka-omg-what-happened-to-my-privileges

Comment: I sure could. But a typical guy looking at his privilege page won't.